IOPub data rate exceeded and changing the Jupyter config file doesn't work
I got this error:
IOPub data rate exceeded.
The Jupyter server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--ServerApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.

Current values:
ServerApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000.0 (bytes/sec)
ServerApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs)

When running this code:
%%time
try: 
    # get the correct ids
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=cnx)
    
    # Create a Session
    session = Session()

    # Reflect the database to get the table metadata
    metadata = MetaData()
    patients_table = Table('ekg_patient_tracings', metadata, autoload_with=cnx)
    
    # Prepare the query
    query = select(patients_table).where(patients_table.c.patient_hash.in_(patient_hashes))
    
    # Execute the query
    result = session.execute(query)

    # Fetch all rows
    rows = result.fetchall()

    df_ekg_ids = pd.DataFrame(rows)

except Exception as e:
    print("An error occurred:", e)
finally:
    # Close the session
    session.close()

So I tried changing the iopub data rate limit. My config file (/home/user/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.json) appears to be changed. Here is what it looks like when I print it:
{ "NotebookApp": { "nbserver_extensions": { "jupyter_nbextensions_configurator": true }, "iopub_data_rate_limit": 10000000000.0, "rate_limit_window": 3.0 }, "ServerApp": { "iopub_data_rate_limit": 10000000000.0, "rate_limit_window": 3.0 } 
However, I continue to get the same error (data rate limit appears unchanged). I have tried restarting the kernel. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? Thank you!
Here is some version information if it matters:
Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 8.25.0
ipykernel        : 6.23.1
ipywidgets       : 8.1.3
jupyter_client   : 8.2.0
jupyter_core     : 5.3.0
jupyter_server   : 2.5.0
jupyterlab       : 4.2.3
nbclient         : 0.7.4
nbconvert        : 7.4.0
nbformat         : 5.8.0
notebook         : 6.4.12
qtconsole        : 5.5.2
traitlets        : 5.14.3


"However, I continue to get the same error (data rate limit appears unchanged). I have tried restarting the kernel." It says that you restarted the kernel. Did you restart everything? Just restarting the kernel isn't going to change anything pertinent because what you changed was a setting at the level of the server  & so you need an entirely new session launched.

@Wayne I just restarted the server and everything is the same (config file looks like the limit is higher, but I am getting the same error showing the low limit)
